# Why does Google give better results than PSE search about PSE's own pages?

Tags: discussion, search

I had been faced with this several times before. But this time I decide to ask it in a Meta post. I typed this phrase in the search box of the PSE:

```
"What is the field in the physics really?"
```

You can see the results [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=What%20is%20the%20field%20in%20the%20physics%20really%3F).

The [question with exactly similar title](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/what-is-a-field-really) is the seventh one.

Then I typed the same phrase in the Google search box. You can see the results [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=What%20is%20the%20field%20in%20the%20physics%20really%3F&rlz=1C1RLNS_enIR698IR698&oq=What%20is%20the%20field%20in%20the%20physics%20really%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.1802j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

As you can see, the same question with exactly similar title belong to PSE is the first one.

I wonder why does Google search PSE's own pages, better than itself?

Comment: Duplicate of [this meta.SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254399/263383). There are lots of similar threads on meta.SE about this, the answer is basically: Because implementing a good search is hard, and Google has been at this for a while.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well! But Google searches all over the internet while PSE search engine searches PSE's own pages only. Is it hard yet?

Comment: Oddly, [the S.E.N.-wide search link](http://stackexchange.com/search) brings up the post in question as its first result. (Maybe not as odd as I had thought at first glance, since it states that it's "powered by Google TM".)

Comment: And, the google watches, what you searched for, and how you clicked. Using this data, he can find out, how useful are the actual links for the actual queries.

Comment: Google looks at literally everything on  the page, the header at the top, the meta description, the links, the whole enchilada. I don't know how pse searches, but I'm pretty sure it searchs less overall content.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has been discussed on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) several times already - see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254399), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185758/should-so-include-a-custom-google-search), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135753/when-searching-is-it-better-to-use-the-built-in-so-search-or-use-google), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107211/how-does-stack-overflows-search-compare-with-googles-site-specific-search), and probably others I haven't caught.

Google was founded in 1998 on a business model based on a search engine. Stack Exchange was founded in 2008 on a business model based on a Q&A engine. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Engineering) is the current SE dev team - how much money and manpower Google invests/has invested on Search is anyone's guess. It's not particularly surprising that Google is good at search (considering, in addition, that SE spends a lot of time and infrastructure making sure that SE is well ranked by Google).

It's also perfectly possible to restrict Google searches to only Stack Exchange pages - try [adding the `site:physics.stackexchange.com` operator to your search](https://www.google.de/search?q=What+is+the+field+in+the+physics+really%3F+site:physics.stackexchange.com). That's a good way to search PSE if you're looking for something specific and having trouble using the site search. (On the other hand, you lose access to the [SE advanced search features](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching) that do use the internal characteristics of the posts database, like the `score:` or `is:question` operators.)

Comment: re: "anyone's guess", it is at least clear we'd be talking about billions of dollars and around a thousand people - the point being that Google search exceeds SE's resources by roughly 2-3 orders of magnitude.

Comment: Why doesn't SE use Google to search its internal pages...

Comment: @Floris Why don't you ask SE themselves? I don't particularly care (the internal search is plenty good and if needed you can just use google directly).

Comment: You don't really need `is:question` when using an external search engine. The internal search looks for posts, which means that every question appears $n+1$ times in the search results, where $n$ is the number of answers. But external search engines look for pages, which already means that each question appears only once.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I hope it's obvious that that was a representative example. If the internal search is in fact replaceable with an external search (including easy-to-use replacements for the `score`, `views`, `user`, `[tag]`, `isanswered`, `hasaccepted`, `isaccepted`, `duplicate`, `hasnotice`, `wiki`, and so on), then I would seriously encourage you to write a suitable tutorial on [meta.se]. Otherwise, I don't really see the point of your comment, I'm afraid.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It wasn't at all obvious to me that it was just a representative example. I guess that's because `is:question` is the only one I ever use.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, for future reference, when someone says "like" *x* or *y*, and provides a link to a full list, it can be a good idea to actually look at the link provided. (Apologies if I sound cross - I'm just annoyed at how obvious the question was and the amount of trivial comments it's generated.)